# HTML5 Range input with Ember

Tags: html, ember.js

I have a range input I use to filter my model which is binded to the value attribute.

```
{{input type="range" class="range" name="range" min="0" max="64" value=bindvalue}}
```

The problem is that it filters for every step you drag the slider, instead of just filter the value when you release the slider. Which really makes the slider lag.
So I thought I could use this instead:

```
<input type="range" onchange="number.value=value" name="range" min="0" max="64" value="0">
{{input type="number" id="number" name="number" value=bindvalue}}
```

The range input sets the number inputs value on release but ember doesn't update my filter when this happens. only when I edit the number input myself.

How would you go about letting ember know when the range input sets the number inputs value?

Comment: Why not add the filtering function in debounce method. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25281767/548568

Comment: @blessenm So the debounce method just delays the observer?
That could work, but if I set it to 2 seconds and a person drags the slider for more than 2 seconds it would lag at the 2 second mark I think.

Comment: Debounce keeps resetting the timer every time you run it. It will only execute 2 seconds after the last call to debounce was made. Here is the doc. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/run.run.html#method_debounce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your last approach and if not debounce is used, as stated here

[Ember.js textField change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538439/ember-js-textfield-change-event)

the field needs to lose focus.

So you can do something like,

```
function updateNumberValue(value){

    var num=document.querySelector("#number");
    num.value=value;
    $(num).blur();
}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fobep/1/edit

Comment: I like this approach more than using debounce. Works perfectly.